# Merge/concat two dataframe by cols

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frame :

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import nan
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'key':[1,2,3,4],
                    'only_at_df1':['a','b','c','d'],
                    'col2':['e','f','g','h'],})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'key':[1,9],
                    'only_at_df2':[nan,'x'],
                    'col2':['e','z'],})
```

How to acquire this:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'key':[1,2,3,4,9],
                    'only_at_df1':['a','b','c','d',nan],
                    'only_at_df2':[nan,nan,nan,nan,'x'],
                    'col2':['e','f','g','h','z'],})
```

any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best is probably to use `combine_first` after temporarily setting "key" as index:

```
df1.set_index('key').combine_first(df2.set_index('key')).reset_index()
```

output:

```
   key col2 only_at_df1 only_at_df2
0    1    e           a         NaN
1    2    f           b         NaN
2    3    g           c         NaN
3    4    h           d         NaN
4    9    z         NaN           x
```

Comment: made my night.may i ask your concern when you say probably?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a straightforward use of `merge` with `how="outer"`:

```
df1.merge(df2, how="outer")
```

Output:

```
   key only_at_df1 col2 only_at_df2
0    1           a    e         NaN
1    2           b    f         NaN
2    3           c    g         NaN
3    4           d    h         NaN
4    9         NaN    z           x
```

Comment: nevermind I thought you provided the `on` parameter, but then I am not sure how this would handle cases where there are matches in col2 (by default not specifying `on` merges on all common columns)

Comment: I know that, you mean something like the first row of both dataframes? It matches both columns as intended

Comment: thanks for approach, in real data this raised: unhashable type: 'list' but works on above sample. maybe i am wrong but there may be a better way than passing fields as on= parameter since there is plenty of heavy string cols.